# One day load in less than a minute and a month load takes several hours in table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

A day load use to take 5 minutes. I changed to parameterized stored procedure, apply indexes as recommended by execution plan and a day dropped to 47 seconds but a month load forever. What could be the problem? Average daily load is about 50, 000 rows.

```
USE [DBl]

--[dbo].[ClosedOrder] StartDate, '@EndDate'
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ClosedOrders] 
 ( @StartDate DATETIME 
  ,@EndDate  DATETIME
 )
AS




 DECLARE @temp_dec DECIMAL(15,2) = 0.00
 DECLARE @temp_int int     = NULL
 DECLARE @temp_str nvarchar(60)  = NULL
 DECLARE @temp_date Date    = NULL
-- Michael Xia changes temp table to table variable on 05/24/2016
DECLARE @lines TABLE
 (
  SalesOrderID nvarchar (20),
  SalesOrderLine smallint,
  CustomerID_SoldTo nvarchar (14),
  OrderDate date,

  )


INSERT INTO @lines
SELECT

-- multiple sub queries like below              
 , (SELECT TOP 1 CAST(sh.ship_date AS DATE)
   FROM dbl.dbo.[Shipments] sh  (NOLOCK)
  WHERE sh.co_num = coi.co_num AND sh.co_line = coi.co_line
    AND sh.shipped=3
  ORDER BY sh.ship_date DESC)               'DateLastShipped'


 ---multiple update to the table variable using scalar function like below
UPDATE @lines
 SET __ServiceLevelDays = CASE
        WHEN ScheduledToShipDate = ShipNoLaterThanDate THEN 1
        ELSE [dbl].[dbo].GetNumberOfBays(SchlShipDate,ShipNoLaterThanDate,1) + 1
           END


TRUNCATE TABLE [DBL].[dbo].[ClosedOrder]

INSERT INTO [DBL].[dbo].[ClosedOrder]

(

)

SELECT 
 *
FROM @lines


END
```

Comment: If I were investigating this I'd run each of the subqueries (from `INSERT INTO @lines`) individually with monthly load parameter values and see if anything stands out.

Comment: You procedure doesn't use the input variables. Perhaps you didn't post the whole procedure. Anyway this could be parameter sniffing, which you can fix with brute force by adding `WITH RECOMPILE` to your SP. Or it could just be that it takes a lot of time. How many records are there in a month?

Comment: The variables are passed in sql agent job’s step. I used recompile option in the select statement to the physical table. We load average of 430k per month.

Comment: The input variables in your stored procedure are never used in your internal code. Your SP still doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

Since, daily load takes couple of seconds (47 seconds to be exact), you need to modify the monthly load by creating a temp table, storing all dates and then creating a loop and adding each day which should take couple of minutes (47 seconds * 30 times) 
Indirectly, reducing the total number of rows to be in memory before written to the database.
Hope that helps.

Comment: No. Never use a loop in a database

Comment: The stored procedure is for daily load. Just need to load one time history from sql agent and subsequently it will be a daily load. But can you provide example of how to implement your recommendations without blowing up TempDB?